# Why is this app code only working from the right side or else the ReactDOM.findDOMNode querySelector cant find className

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I learn Reactjs and Javascript and have a questions regarding this small one file
Codesandbox [Hover effect REACT (forked)](https://codesandbox.io/s/hover-effect-react-forked-ey2ze?file=/src/App.js).
The app is sliding in an overlay with text when mouse moves over it and the overlay hides when mouse leave.

Why is it only often working when mouse enter and exist from the right side? Try it you'll see kind of strange..

I see this error:

[image]

I check in the DOM and there is a correct `className` I think so maybe it's I'm using some mix of wrong version imports or it's a timing issue?

I made a [movie clips](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z3PshHaM6n6cfXun3n7IFxZVl138_v5_/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `handleMouseLeave`, event target will be children component like( p, h2, h3,...). So, `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(e.target).querySelector` can not find outer like `.box-content`.

I suggest simple solution use `useState`.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        posts: [],
        hoverIndex: null,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        axios
            .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`)
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({ posts: res.data });
            })
            .then((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    handleMouseEnter = (e) => {
        if (e.target.id !== null) {
            this.setState({hoverIndex: e.target.id});
        }
    };

    handleMouseLeave = (e) => {
        this.setState({hoverIndex: null});
    };

    render() {
        const { posts } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                {posts.map((e, index) => (
                    <div
                        onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
                        onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
                        className={"box-container"}
                        id={index}
                        key={e.id}
                    >
                        <h3>HOVER ME</h3>
                        <div
                            className={"box-content " + (this.state.hoverIndex === index.toString() ? 'hovered' : "")}
                        >
                            <h2>{e.title}</h2>
                            <p>{e.body}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I learn so much your the best. I also added a `onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}`in the   `className="box-content"` so that that the overlay retracts when mouse leave it, this way the message (the overlay) was displayed and the hole "hover me" can be viewed. Lets say it's a text document..

Comment: I will use that overlay on [my project](https://github.com/erikswed/Greta-100-React-Web-App) , comming from Android so it's a steep learning curve please join and help out